# Cannot import scripts Node.js server

Tags: html, node.js, scripting, socket.io

I'm creating an http server with node that reads a simple html file. This html file imports some scripts that are located in my computer. Node cannot load this scripts. Why?

```
    var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(2210);
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res){
    fs.readFile("./index.html", function(err, data){
        if (err){
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end("Error loading index.html");
        }
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
            res.end(data, 'utf-8');
    });
}).listen(2211);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

});
```

And here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>ASGEAWER</title> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.splitview.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile.grids.collapsible.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.splitview.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="servernode.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="interaction.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready",inici);
  </script>
</head> 

  <body> 

    <div data-role="panel" data-id="menu" data-hash="crumbs" data-context="a#default">

      <!-- Start of first page -->
      <div data-role="page" id="main" data-hash="false">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Categoria</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
          <ul data-role="listview">

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div><!-- /page -->

    </div><!-- panel menu -->






    <div data-role="panel" data-id="main">
      <!-- Start of 6th page -->
      <div data-role="page" id="aboutsv">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
          <h1>Productos</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content"> 
        </div><!-- /content -->
      </div><!-- /page -->

    </div><!-- panel main -->


  </body>
</html>
```

And chrome gives me those errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.7.1.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.mobile.splitview.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery.mobile.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < servernode.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < interaction.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This html file imports some scripts that are located in my computer

What the browser does when it finds a `<script>` tag with a src attribute is to make another request to the server (your node http server in this case) requesting for that file.

In your case, your server responds to each request with the index.html content.

So, in order to import that files you must alter your http.createServer callback for responding to every static file request with the content of that file instead of responding always with the index.html content

It should be something like this:

First, create a function for dealing with content types

```
function contentType(ext) {
    var ct;

    switch (ext) {
    case '.html':
        ct = 'text/html';
        break;
    case '.css':
        ct = 'text/css';
        break;
    case '.js':
        ct = 'text/javascript';
        break;
    default:
        ct = 'text/plain';
        break;
    }

    return {'Content-Type': ct};
}
```

Then,  redefine your server code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var HTTP_OK = 200,
    HTTP_ERR_UNKNOWN = 500,
    HTTP_ERR_NOT_FOUND = 404;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var filepath = '.' + (req.url == '/' ? index : req.url),
        fileext = path.extname(filepath); 

    path.exists(filepath, function (f) {
        if (f) {
            fs.readFile(filepath, function (err, content) {
                if (err) {
                    res.writeHead(HTTP_ERR_UNKNOWN);
                    res.end();
                } else {
                    res.writeHead(HTTP_OK, contentType(fileext));
                    res.end(content);
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.writeHead(HTTP_ERR_NOT_FOUND);
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
```

This is a simple homemade static server, **but better if you use a library for this**:

- **Simple static server:** https://github.com/jesusabdullah/node-ecstatic
- A complete framework: http://expressjs.com/